# what browsers is jquery bootstrap compatible with?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I found this neat code at:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

It doesn't write anywhere what browsers it's compatible with ...I assume with all new ones, but what about IE6 or IE7?

Again, sorry if this is the wrong place to ask but I couldn't think of a better place than this awesome community!

Comment: See the homepage: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. "Originally built with only modern browsers in mind, Bootstrap has evolved to include support for all major browsers (even IE7!) and, with Bootstrap 2, tablets and smartphones, too."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's definitely compatible with IE7:](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html)

> #### Cross-everything
>
> Originally built with only modern browsers in mind, Bootstrap has evolved to include support for all major browsers (even IE7!) and, with Bootstrap 2, tablets and smartphones, too.

...and please don't tell me you actually care about IE6 support. Anyway, [it's not supported](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/737), although [there is a set of unofficial fixes for IE6 support](https://github.com/empowering-communities/Bootstrap-IE6).

Comment: Thank you! How did I miss that ..I guess they wrote TOO much.